# Get rid of the redundant/misleading "complete bounties list" link on Bounties tab

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties

On the bottom of [Bounties tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties) we have the link to [complete list of bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Bounties):

> [image]

> Looking for more questions with bounties? Browse the complete list.

Do we actually need it when ALL bounties are already listed here?
This may lead users to think that there are more bounties on the site- but there are not. Could we simply remove that link?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, there are nearly 200 bountied questions, but only ~100 are listed at https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties. The full list is only found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Bounties.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Thank you for clarification, I know it. That's because I stated "**when ALL bounties** are already listed". Maybe it's better to improve wording in my FR.